# Dojo CDN with source version?

Tags: dojo

Does anyone know of a CDN or other hosted version of Dojo that includes the full source? This would be handy for debugging purposes.

Thanks,

Karl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google has one](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#dojo):

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js

Answer (score 1):

[AOL](http://dev.aol.com/dojo) also has one:

```
http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/<version>/dojo/dojo.xd.js
http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/<version>/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js
```

Comment: hmm... so AOL is no longer a partner of Dojo Foundation any more?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Just that for whatever reason, the CDN has not been updated upon request.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest Dojo sourcecode (1.7.2) go to Dojo site and download the SDK: [Full scource SDK as a zip file](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.2/dojo-release-1.7.2-src.zip)

Answer (score 0):

http://yandex.st/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js (Yandex is russian search engine)